# How to add vectors in Ada

Tags: vector, ada, gnat-gps

I have a vector of the form (x,y,x) representing coordinates. I want to be able to do something like (x,y,z) + (x2,y2,z2) to produce a new set of coordinates. Ada says it cant use '+' for composite types, but surely there is a way I can do this?

Comment: How did you define your vector? Please read thIs: [mre].

Comment: And be sure to show us the exact error message in your question. Ada certainly can apply `+` to composite types if you define it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have

```ada
type Vector is record
   X : Float;
   Y : Float;
   Z : Float;
end record;
```

you can define `+` as

```ada
function "+" (L, R : Vector) return Vector is
  (L.X + R.X, L.Y + R.Y, L.Z + R.Z);
```

Be careful when you define `-` similarly to use `-` throughout! that error is *very* hard to spot.

Answer (score 3):

If you define your vectors to contain elements of a floating point type you can use the generic package Ada.Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays. This package is described in the Ada Language Reference Manual section G.3.1.

If you want to define your vectors to contain elements of a complex number type then you can use the generic package described in section G.3.2 *Complex Vectors and Matrices*

If you wish to use integer types as your vector components you can write the "+" function for your integer vector type.